# Limit the use of java annotations

Tags: java, annotations

There is a way to limit the number of use for a java annotation inside a class?

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Inherited
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    //
}
```

What i want:

```
public class MyClass{

    @MyAnnotation
    private Object obj1;

    private Object obj2;
}
```

What i want to prevent:

```
public class MyClass{

    @MyAnnotation
    private Object obj1;

    @MyAnnotation //should throw an error because already used on another field
    private Object obj2;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you want that one annotation influences all members of a class, why don't you write an annotation at class level.

Comment: Because i want to access to the field having this annotation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Once you have `@Target(ElementType.FIELD)` on your annotation, you cannot enforce a compile-time check on the number of fields your annotation may be applied to. You can, of course check it during processing, but it is not a compile-time check.

Comment: You mean i can check if i remove @Target annotation?
For now I'm checking during process yes.

Comment: @L.Andia No. I meant if you let your annotation be applicable to fields, it will be applicable to any number of fields.

Comment: ok thank you. so i guess your answer is it's not possible at compile-time.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  You can write a compile-time annotation processor that enforces this check.  Running an annotation processor via Java's standard `-processor` command-line argument is a compile-time check.  (There is also run-time processing, which is not a compile-time check.)